# How can I make an animated svg pie chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, charts

I need to make an svg pie chart with animation with three values and can't find my mistakes in the code. When I remove the setTimeout(function(){
  circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", p + " 100");
  }, 10); from the JavaScript the pie chart looks ok but is not animated. When I add that pieceof code it is animated but doesn't load all values and loads anticlockwise instead of clockwise. I don't know any javascript but needed to add two extra values to an existing pie chart and using the given javascript I created two additional circles. The animation worked fine where there was only one circle. I notice that the end result(the pink pie that stays after the animation ends) comes from the value  in the .pie div 35  but if I leave the div empty the whole pie chart disappears.

```
HTML
 <div class="widgets">
  <div class="left box stats">
  <div class="content">
  <div class="widget-row">
     <div class="stat stat--pie stat--productivity">
       <div class="pie">35</div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

CSS
.box.stats .stat.stat--pie {
  width: 170px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.box.stats  .stat.stat--pie .pie {
  position: relative;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
}

.box.stats  .stat.stat--pie .pie > svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
}

.box.stats  .stat.stat--pie .pie > svg circle {
  -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 1.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 1.2s ease-out;
}

.box.stats .content .stat.stat--productivity .pie svg  {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.box.stats .content .stat.stat--productivity .pie svg circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #283250;
  stroke-width: 32;
}

.box.stats .content .stat.stat--productivity .pie svg .circle2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #E8E05A;
  stroke-width: 32;
}

.box.stats .content .stat.stat--productivity .pie svg .circle3 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #E24264;
  stroke-width: 32;
}

JavaScript 
function $$(selector, context) {
context = context || document;
var elements = context.querySelectorAll(selector);
return Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);
}

$$('.stat--productivity .pie').forEach(function(pie) {
  var p = parseFloat(pie.textContent);
  var NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  var svg = document.createElementNS(NS, "svg");
  var circle = document.createElementNS(NS, "circle");
  var circle2 = document.createElementNS(NS, "circle");
  var circle3 = document.createElementNS(NS, "circle");
  var digit = document.createElement("H1");
  var percent = document.createElement("span");


  circle.setAttribute("r", 16);
  circle.setAttribute("cx", 16);
  circle.setAttribute("cy", 16);
  circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", "100 100");
  setTimeout(function(){
  circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", p + " 100");
  }, 10);


  circle2.classList.add('circle2');
  circle2.setAttribute("r", 16);
  circle2.setAttribute("cx", 16);
  circle2.setAttribute("cy", 16);
  circle2.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", "90 100");
  setTimeout(function(){
    circle2.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", p + " 100");
  }, 10);

  circle3.classList.add('circle3');
  circle3.setAttribute("r", 16);
  circle3.setAttribute("cx", 16);
  circle3.setAttribute("cy", 16);
  circle3.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", "50 100");
  setTimeout(function(){
    circle3.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", p + " 100");
  }, 10);


  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 32 32");
  digit.textContent = pie.textContent;
  percent.textContent = '%';
  pie.textContent = '';

  pie.appendChild(svg);
  svg.appendChild(circle);
  svg.appendChild(circle2);
  svg.appendChild(circle3);
  pie.appendChild(digit);
  pie.appendChild(percent);

});

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjRYwR
```

Comment: Your `div` with value is read by javascript as `p` variable to set final value of circle animation. And even if just first circle is left (commenting out 2nd and 3rd circle in javascript) then animation is still anti-clockwise. Inside call `setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", ...)` change order of to `p+ " 100"` first (that is same as "35 100") and `"100 100"` later and you will have clockwise animation.

Comment: Could you please add more details on what I need to change? Coudln't really understand and it didn't work.

Comment: I am puzzled, example on jsfiddle works as you described. You need to copy content from jsfiddle and update your JS and CSS and then content of HTML div as said in description. If you cannot handle answer I am not sure what community can do for you...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the other answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example of multi-value chart that unfolds clockwise: https://jsfiddle.net/bowkugsq/

There are multiple changes to original code, yet I tried to preserve as much as possible to let OP understand changes and apply to own solution.

CSS has enumerated classes for each `circle` with index postfix. There is also set of classes for `label`s (legend) to reflect colors of pie chart and make furhter customizations. If one wants to add next piece to chart it required adding one more `circle` and `label` class.

Most complex refactoring is done to pie generation (explanation below):

```
$$('.stat--productivity .pie').forEach(function(pie) {
  var percents = pie.textContent.split(",");
  percents = percents.map(function(pct, idx) {
    return {
      value: parseFloat(pct),
      sum: 0,
      idx: idx + 1
    }
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < percents.length; i++) {
    var prevSum = (i > 0) ? percents[i - 1].sum : 1;
    percents[i].sum = prevSum + percents[i].value;
  };
  percents.reverse();
  var NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  var svg = document.createElementNS(NS, "svg");
  pie.textContent = ''; //clear div
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 32 32");
  pie.appendChild(svg);
  percents.forEach(function(pct, idx) {
    var circle = document.createElementNS(NS, "circle");
    circle.classList.add("circle" + pct.idx);
    circle.setAttribute("r", 16);
    circle.setAttribute("cx", 16);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", 16);
    circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", "0 100");
    setTimeout(function() {
      circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", pct.sum + " 100");
    });
    svg.appendChild(circle);
  });
  percents.forEach(function(pct, idx) {
    var digit = document.createElement("span");
    digit.textContent = pct.value + " %";
    digit.classList.add("label" + (idx + 1));
    pie.appendChild(digit);
  });
});
```

First of all main pie div contains now comma separated list of percentages like this: `<div class="pie">25,15,60</div>`. They must sum up to 100% otherwise circle will not close up. Initially text content is split by commas into `percents` array that is later converted into array of objects with extra index and partial sums; for given sample it would yield `[{value:25,sum:25,idx:1}, {value:15,sum:40,idx:2}, {value:60,sum:100,idx:3}]`. In fact `sum` are upshifted by extra 1% as range "100 100" for "stroke-dasharray" leads to tiny slot not closing full circle. Such array of objects is reversed to make animated pieces not overlaping each other. Next `circle` elements are created for each percentage as in original OP code. Finally `percent` array is processed to add `span`s with labels with original values.

Disclaimer: code could be structured better however resemblence of original approach was main driving force.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to learn something new and improve your coding skills it's ok to try and code it yourself, but if you need this for any other reason I would suggest not trying to reinvent the wheeel and using something that's 'ready-to-use'

Take a look at this: [PieGraph](https://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Pie-Donut-Chart-SVG-jChart.html)

Comment: I corrected my question: I needed to add two more values to an existing pie chart and used the given code. The chart looked fine at first before adding the extra two values but I don't know where my mistakes are.